# Android maps zoom - OutOfMemory

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming, out-of-memory

When I zoom in/zoom out from time to time in my map activity I get in console an "OutOfMemory error:bitmap size exceeds VM budget". The app doesn't crash on my developement phone, but I'm not sure If this issue won't cause a problem in future.

Note: I display maximum 30 custom markers on map.

The error stack doesn't reference my code. Does anyone have a fix or a best practice to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
...
marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
...
fillData();
}
public void fillData() {
...
  for (int i = 0; i < lats.length; i++) {
    ...
    map.getOverlays().add(new ContactOverlay(marker, tempLat, tempLon, names[i],
                phones[i]));
   }
}

private class ContactOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public ContactOverlay(Drawable marker, double latitude,
            double longitude, String title, String snippet) {
        super(marker);
        boundCenterBottom(marker); 
        items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(longitude, latitude), title,
                snippet)); 
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (items.get(i));
    }
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reuse the bitmap and the canvas where you draw. Each time when you redraw the overlay, a new bitmap is allocated.

Comment: Can u give me a link or a source code where there are no memory leaks problems(caused by multiple zoom in/out, map translation) when adding overlays in a map?

Comment: I think this is not a memory leak. As far as i know, when you allocate new bitmap and there is not enough memory, an exception is thrown and then GC starts and frees older allocations. I do not know why the system works like that, but this is the problem here.

Comment: I've updated my post with a code fragment which causes somethimes OutOfMemory exception. Do you think that I made something wrong? Thanks Pepi.

Comment: How ?(Try to reuse the bitmap and the canvas where you draw. Each time when you redraw the overlay, a new bitmap is allocated.)Please i have facing same problem.Dorin and Pepi can you post the solution because you have marked the answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

@dorin, I post an answer because the answer is too long.

I think it is ok, but this is not the problem.
Each time when you redraw the overlay a new bitmap is created.You can not see it, because this happens in onDraw method and the overlay do it. So, lets imagine you redraw the overlay 10 times. 10 bitmaps are created. If the GC do not clean this 10 bitmaps, when you create the next one, the OS is trying to allocate memory for new bitmap. If there is not enough memory in the heap, an exception is thrown and then GC frees the memory that was allocated for the previous 10 bitmaps. The thing you have to do is to avoid this bitmap memory allocation. Create base overlay class and extend the ItemizedOverlay. Override the onDraw() Method and create a bitmap field. Each time onDraw() is called, recycle the bitmap and draw again on it. On this way you avoid a new bitmap recreation -> OutOfMemory exception too

Comment: Thanks. If is not to much trouble for you, can u please edit my source code post according to your explanation to be sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: It is not so easy...It is a lot of code. Search for some examples how to draw over bitmap, how to use canvas and so on..